# Does InstallUtil automatically register .dlls for you?

Tags: c#, dll, installutil

I am transitioning from a PowerShell script to a C# Console App executing InstallUtil.exe via Process()class  to silently install a windows service.

In the PowerShell script I had to register each .dll the service uses with regsvr32.exe

Does the InstallUtil.exe automatically register the needed .dlls by examining the passed assembly for a list of the .dlls and then register them?

I read through the following link, but it did not mention .dlls:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/installutil-exe-installer-tool

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer through testing (yes the .dlls are automatically registered).

1. I uninstalled the service.
2. I manually ran regsvr32 /u to confirm the .dlls were unregistered.
3. I ran the install ConsoleApp that runs InstallUtil.exe
4. The service was installed and started up correctly.